# console write line every 8 characters

Tags: vb.net, binary, console

I'm converting text to binary, and sending that information to the console. However, I want the console to write a new line for every 8 characters.

My convert to binary code looks like this (where `Result.Text` contains random text, that will be converted)

```
 Dim Resultconvert As String = ""
 For Each C As Char In Result.Text
   Dim s As String = System.Convert.ToString(AscW(C), 2).PadLeft(8, "0")
   Resultconvert &= s
 Next
 Console.WriteLine(Resultconvert)
```

So it should look like this:

```
01110010
01111110
01101111
01011100
01100100
01010001
01001101
00111010
01010100
```

instead of:

```
011100100111111001101111010111000110010001010001010011010011101001010100
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Dim Resultconvert As String = String.Empty

    For Each C As Char In Result.Text
        Dim s As String = System.Convert.ToString(AscW(C), 2).PadLeft(8, "0")
        Debug.Print(s)
        Resultconvert &= s
    Next
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply roryap! No luck sadly. Still writes as one line.

Comment: @user3403843 Sorry, that's what I get for trying it outside of the IDE.  I modified it.

Comment: @user3403843 -- just modified again...left my test string in there by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to just call `WriteLine` separately for each byte, like this:

```
For Each C As Char In Result.Text
    Dim s As String = System.Convert.ToString(AscW(C), 2).PadLeft(8, "0")
    Console.WriteLine(s)
Next
```

However, if you want to write it all at once, you need to append a new line to the string after each byte, like this:

```
Dim Resultconvert As String = ""
For Each C As Char In Result.Text
    Dim s As String = System.Convert.ToString(AscW(C), 2).PadLeft(8, "0")
    Resultconvert &= s & Environment.NewLine
Next
Console.WriteLine(Resultconvert)
```

But, at that point, it would be easier and more efficient to use a `StringBuilder`:

```
Dim builder As New StringBuilder()
For Each C As Char In Result.Text
    Dim s As String = System.Convert.ToString(AscW(C), 2).PadLeft(8, "0")
    builder.AppendLine(s)
Next
Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString())
```